# SSH Connect to hosts by using tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to `ssh` connect from host `A` to host `C` directly with one `ssh` command.

```
+---+       +---+       +---+
| A |   ->  | B |   ->  | C |
+---+       +---+       +---+
```

Host `A` already have keys configured to access host `B` (when I run `ssh B` from A it works)

Host `B` already have keys configured to access host `C` (when I run `ssh C` from B it works)

Host `A` username is `daniel`
Host `B` username is `ubuntu`
Host `C` username is `ubuntu`

Hosts `B`, and `C` are referenced by IP address rather than by name.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it directly from the command line like this:

```
ssh -A -t ubuntu@hostB ssh -A hostC
```

Or by adding these lines to your `"$HOME"/.ssh/config` file and invoking `ssh hostC` in the normal manner:

```
Host hostB
        User ubuntu

Host hostC
        User ubuntu
        ProxyCommand ssh -q hostB nc -q0 %h %p
```

In your scenario where `hostB` and `hostC` are referenced by IP address, simply put those IP addresses in place. (You may need `ubuntu@hostB` in the `ProxyCommand` field.)

There are more details available in the article [Transparent Multi-hop SSH](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html)

Comment: method one worked, but method two returned `Permission denied (publickey).` - I have added to the config file HostName <server ip> on both servers

Comment: keys on hostA and hostB are different

Comment: @DanielCukier adding HostName shouldn't fix a `Permission denied` error. You might want to look in the log files on the respective servers to see what it thinks is happening

Comment: hostB sshd[1783]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
hostB sshd[1783]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from <hostA ip> port 49545 ssh2: RSA b3:b1:db:23:b4:0f:18:ea:9d:ba:ba:b6:1e:6a:a9:af
hostB sshd[1783]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
hostB kernel: [11574132.566968] systemd-logind[1837]: New session 4490 of user ubuntu.
hostB sshd[1843]: Received disconnect from <hostA ip>: 11: disconnected by user
hostB sshd[1783]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user

Comment: hostC sshd[4708]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
hostC sshd[4708]: Connection closed by 10.240.178.10 [preauth]

Comment: @DanielCukier please remove the `HostName` entries that you added. If hostA can reach hostB, and hostB can reach hostC, you shouldn't add `HostName` entries.

Comment: In hostname I put the servers ip. I need it to identify the servers. They don't have public names

Comment: @Daniel you said in your Question that `hostA` could reach `hostB`, and `hostB` could reach `hostC`. Replace `hostB` and `hostC` in my examples with your `hostB` and `hostC` and it will work. Otherwise you're changing the goalposts.

Comment: `hostB` is an alias to one IP address, that is reachable from `hostA`. `hostC` is another alias to one IP address that is reachable from `hostB`